# How to delete Reverse value In SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am fetching  all reverse value from SQL using following Query

```
select a.* from TotalsByGLCenter$ as a
left join TotalsByGLCenter$ as b on a.APSupplierID = b.APSupplierID AND a.Entity=b.Entity and a.ExpenseReportID=b.ExpenseReportID and a.Employee=b.Employee  and a.Amount = -b.Amount
where b.Amount is not null
```

I have Totally 5000 Lines . i have same value  negative and positive  i called its reverse value . i get all reverse value from table totally reverse value 1508 column  out of 5000 lines . above i mention Query used fetch reverse value. i want to delete reverse value

Comment: Your requirement is not clear

Comment: You mean to say negative values?

Comment: Do you mean delete all rows where another row exists for the same supplier, with the same amount, but negative? E.g. rows that cancel each others' value out?

Comment: I have Totally 5000 Lines . i have same value  negative and positive  i called its reverse value . i get all reverse value from table totally reverse value 1508 column  out of 5000 lines . above i mention Query used fetch reverse value. i want to delete reverse value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the exact same records returned by your query, here is how you do it (you just have to proportionate the alias of the table you want to delete from) :

```
delete a 
from TotalsByGLCenter$ as a
left join TotalsByGLCenter$ as b on a.APSupplierID = b.APSupplierID AND a.Entity=b.Entity and a.ExpenseReportID=b.ExpenseReportID and a.Employee=b.Employee  and a.Amount = -b.Amount
where b.Amount is not null
```